# Iphone application is not showing on iPad app center

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

We have created one mobile app using MobileFirst 7.1 whoe family type is iPhone. When we tried to install it on iPad through app center, it was not available there. I know iPhone application is not compatible on iPad and normall run in 2x mode but application should be listed on IBM App center atleast. Are we missing any setting?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's available for apps that are marked as Universal, not as iPhone. iPhone is for iPhone, iPad is for iPad and Universal is for both (and hopefully in Universal you've included the appropriate graphics, otherwise you'd need to tap the x2 button.

Comment: I agree, we need to click on 2x button. But, app center should not restrict me to download the application. Even on playstore, application which are compatible on iPhone are available to download and user can view in 2X mode. Also, few weeks back I was able to see the application in iPad app center also.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem silly but did you check this setting at the top?

[image]

Comment: I am asking about IBM App center not itunes